# Jquery Validator and Laravel 4 ajax issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i´m trying to validate a form in laravel 4 with Jquery Validator, the only thing i can´t perform it´s a remote validation for the email.

I tried with my browser the following

```
http://example.com/validacion/email/info@info.com
```

and i get the result (in json) that i want.

```
//Routes.php 
Route::get('validacion/email/{email}', 'ValidatorController@getValidacionEmail');

//In my JS the rule of email is
         email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "/validacion/email/",
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    email: "akatcheroff@gmail.com"
                },
                complete: function(data) {
                    if (data.responseText !== "true") {
                        alert(data.respuesta);
                    }
                }
         }
```

And when i use Firebug I get this location

```
http://example.com/validacion/email/?email=akatcheroff%40gmail.com
```

and a 301 code and after that a 500 and this error

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException","message":"","file":"C:\Users\Usuario\Dropbox\Public\sitios\futbol\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php","line":1429}}

Does anybody knows if there is a way to send my mail parameter in a way that the route recognize it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing trailing slash at the end of your ajax url `url: "/validacion/email",` and remove the `{email}` parameter on your route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

The route you have specified `validacion/email/{email}` will handle routes such as:

(1) `http://mysite.com/validacion/email/info@info.com`
(Just like you tried in Firefox.)

When your ajax runs you end up (just as firebug dumped) with urls such as:

(2) `http://mysite.com/validacion/email/?email=info@info.com`

Now notice the difference between url *1* and *2*. The first one have the email value as a segment of the url. The second have the email value as part of the query string.

The error Laravel throws is saying that the router couldn't find a matching handler for the url.

#### Solutions

You can solve this by either changing your javascript:

```
remote: {
    url: "/validacion/email/" + "info@info.com",
    type: "get"
}
```

Remove the email from the query string and add it to the path.

Or, you can solve it by changing your PHP route:

```
Route::get('validacion/email', 'ValidatorController@getValidacionEmail');
```

Then in `getValidacionEmail` you can get the email from the query string using:

```
$email = Input::get('email');
```